# select count of records between 4 and 12 months

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I Have a query to count the records which are aged between 4 and 12 months in my table

```
SELECT count(*) 
from tm_process_state 
where tstamp BETWEEN  ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -12) 
                 AND  LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 4);
```

After running am getting count value as 1240, which is wrong. As it is counting records from 01/03/13 to 27/02/2014.

What i am trying to count is records between sysdate-90 and sysdate-365.

Then I tried below condition

```
 tstamp < sysdate-90 and tstamp>sysdate-365
```

Now the count is 598, which is correct.
But here, I cannot give here like 365(As it varies based on leap and non-leap year)

can any one please tell me how to alter the first query to display correct count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition:

```
where tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -12) AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 4)
```

is calculating from the *beginning* for the months (due to the `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')`) to the end of a month Why not just do:

```
where tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3)
```

If you are concerned about time values on the dates, just `trunc()` the values:

```
where tstamp BETWEEN trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)) AND trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need this:

```
select
  trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12),'MONTH') ,
  LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -4))
from dual;
```

instead of:

```
select
  ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -12) ,
  LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 4)
from dual;
```

see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/26418

Answer (score 0):

you want use simply  sum function

like this

```
        SELECT SUM(case when transits.direction = 1 then 1 else 0 end) ,
        SUM(case when transits.direction = 0 then 1 else 0 end) from t1 t 
        where t.device in ('A','B') group by t.device
```

I do not know actual condion in your query so ...

```
SELECT  
sum(case when tstamp BETWEEN  ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -12) then 1 else 0 end) as yearCount ,
sum(case when LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 4) then 1 else 0 end) as lastThreeMonth
FROM tm_process_state
```